# Visualisation of equipotential surface - linear charge

Tags: physics

I am completely new in Mathematica "programming" language.
At the university in Electrodynamics, we have gotten a homework to visualise the equipotential surfaces with function ContourPlot3D.
I have been able to get the matematical expression for such surface,
the equation should be seen on the picture.
My lastest try to write the function has been:

```
ContourPlot3D[
 log (((L/2 + x) + ((((((L/2) + x)^(2)) + ((y)^(2))))^(1/2)))/((-L/2 +
          x) + ((((((-L/2) + x)^(2)) + ((y)^(2))))^(1/2)))) == 
  0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

or

```
ContourPlot3D[(
   ln (((1/2 + 
          x) + ((((((1/2) + x)^(2)) + ((y)^(2))))^(1/2)))/((-1/2 + 
          x) + ((((((-1/2) + x)^(2)) + ((y)^(2))))^(1/2))))) == 
  0, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Although I have resigned on any parameters and only the variables stayed, still I can not plot the function.
Could anyone to look, where I do a mistake. In all cases is the syntax error, that "more input needed", but I don't know, what more I should define.

[image]

Comment: Functions in Mathematica, such as `Log` are called using square brackets, so you'd want to use `Log[....] == 0`

Comment: Before trying to get good results with `ContourPlot3D` (without knowing proper ranges and contours) I would strongly recommend using `Plot` for fixed x and y or `Plot3D` for fixed y or x to get a feeling for the potential at hand. For this potential `ContourPlot` will most definitely be the more insightful then `ContourPlot3D`, since the potential is axis-symmetric. Further the result for the integral does not hold for arbitrary x, y, and z.

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[(Log@(((1/2 + 
         x) + ((((((1/2) + x)^(2)) + ((y)^(2))))^(1/2)))/((-1/2 + 
         x) + ((((((-1/2) + x)^(2)) + ((y)^(2))))^(1/2))))), {x, -2, 
  2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like N0va said:

Try

```
Plot3D[((1/2 + x + Sqrt[1/4 + x + x^2 + y^2])/(-(1/2) + x + Sqrt[(-(1/2) + x)^2 + y^2])), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

or

```
ContourPlot[((1/2 + x + Sqrt[1/4 + x + x^2 + y^2])/(-(1/2) + x + Sqrt[(-(1/2) + x)^2 + y^2])), {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

to see the potential or the equipotential lines.

Comment: Thank you all very much, I think, that I know at this moment much more and I am able to plot the function.
Thank you for your help!